# Why does Robert Baratheon want to "Burn them all"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

So, in one of the very first episodes of [Game of Thrones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones), Robert Baratheon and Barristan Selmy are telling war stories whilst the Kingslayer stands guard.

Robert, who is severely drunk, asked Jaime what the Mad King's last words were. Jaime said "*He said the same thing you've been saying for hours... burn them all!*"

Now I know why Aerys Targaeryen was saying that, but why was Robert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a [misquote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6GW03WsFgU&t=244)*, (this links to a video of the conversation at that point) If you slow it down in settings, Jaime says, "He'd said the same thing HE'D been saying for hours."

The Mad King liked to burn his enemies; which included Roberts father, Eddard's father... generally everyone. SO, even while he was dying, he was raving about burning people to death (hence the title *Mad King*).

---

<sub>* Video does not work on SE</sub>

Comment: Meh, doesn't really add so much to *Bill*'s 6 hours old answer.

Comment: The Mad King in this instance was talking about the caches if Wildfire under King's Landing - "burn them all" refers to every inhabitant of KL.

Answer (score 20):

If you listen closely at the 4:10 mark on [Game of Thrones - War Stories](https://youtu.be/q6GW03WsFgU), you can hear that the line is:

> He said the same thing **he'd** been saying for hours, "Burn them all."

So it was Aerys Targaryen, not Robert Baratheon, who had been saying "Burn them all" for hours.